# Bootstrap - Tablet View - Text/Image Position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Boostrap. Is it possible to float my text to the right of my image on Tablet portrait orientation?

Here's what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16710/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></a></p>
<h4 class="service-heading">Formula 1</h4>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore.</p>
</p></div>
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></a></p>
<h4 class="service-heading">Rugby</h4>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore.</p>
</p></div>
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></a></p>
<h4 class="service-heading">Football</h4>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore.</p>
</p></div>

</div>
```

Right now, the text lies underneath at Desktop & Mobile, but I'd like at Tablet for it to sit to the right of the image.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

**col-xs**

is what you need to add when you are in mobile view

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-2 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></a></p>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-2">
<h4 class="service-heading">Formula 1</h4>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.......
</div>
```

Comment: Oooooooh. I've always seen those but never understood what it meant until now :-D

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use simple css and media queries instead of using boostrap's typical classes..
This code will work for your screen sizes upto 600px width
here is the css

```
    @media screen & max-width(max-width: 600px) {float: left;margin-left:4%;} div p {float: right;margin-right: 4%;}}
```

Comment: Hi @Zaki, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for me. Is the CSS valid?

Comment: hi you can put the written content in a div with a class and add the css given below

Answer (score 1):

OHH sorry..i mistyped. This one should work for tablet

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
{
.img-responsive {
float: left;
margin-left:4%;
} 
h4 {float: right;
margin-right: 4%;
margin-botttom: 2%;
}
 p {
float: right;
margin-right: 4%;}
}}
```